# Subtraction of two series from different parts of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
        SID     AID          START           END
71       1       1          -11136          -11122   
74       1       1          -11121          -11109   
78       1       1          -11034          -11014   
79       1       2          -11137          -11152   
83       1       2          -11114          -11127   
86       1       2          -11032          -11038
88       1       2          -11121          -11002
```

I want to do a subtraction of the START elements with AID==1 and AID==2, in order, such that the expected result would be:

```
-11136 - (-11137) = 1

-11121 - (-11114) =-7

-11034 - (-11032) =-2

Nan    - (-11002) = NaN
```

So I extracted two groups:

```
values1 = group.loc[group['AID'] == 1]["START"]
values2 = group.loc[group['AID'] == 2]["START"]
```

with the following result:

```
71   -11136
74   -11121
78   -11034
Name: START, dtype: int64
79   -11137
83   -11114
86   -11032
88   -11002
Name: START, dtype: int64
```

and did a simple subtraction:

```
values1-values2
```

But I got all NaNs:

```
71   NaN
74   NaN
78   NaN
79   NaN
83   NaN
86   NaN
```

I noticed that if I use data from the same AID group (e.g. START-END), I get the right answer. I get the NaN only when I "mix" AID group.  I'm just getting started with Pandas, but I'm obviously missing something here. Any suggestion?

Comment: try: 
values1.values - values2.values

Comment: What you are missing is that Pandas does intrinsic data alignment.  Meaning that pandas will subtract based on the indexes of both dataframes.  Since the row index don't align you are getting a number minus NaN or NaN minus a number and those equal NaN.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks! values1.values works if the arrays are of the same dimensions. What if there were more values in "values1" than in "values2"? Numpy doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: What do you expect to happen in this case? Please update your question with example input and desired output.

Comment: please see above

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

```
df.set_index([df.groupby(['SID','AID']).cumcount(),'AID'])['START'].unstack().add_prefix('col_').eval('col_1 - col_2')
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1   -7.0
2   -2.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @user2920100  Updated with new output.

Answer (score 1):

pandas does those operations based on labels. Since your labels ((71, 74, 78) and (79, 83, 86)) don't match, it cannot find any value to subtract. One way to deal with this is to use a numpy array instead of a Series so there is no label associated:

```
values1 - values2.values
Out: 
71    1
74   -7
78   -2
Name: START, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks! What if there were more values in "values1" than in "values2"?  Numpy doesn't seem to like that.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre way to go about it

```
-np.diff([g.reset_index(drop=True) for n, g in df.groupby('AID').START])[0]

0    1.0
1   -7.0
2   -2.0
3    NaN
Name: START, dtype: float64
```